# SQL JOIN clause

Tags: sql

I am running into this problem:

```
SELECT CHILD_NAME, EMP_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE
ON CUSTOMER.CHILD_NAME = EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME
ORDER BY CHILD_NAME ASC;
```

I am coming up with a column (child_name) of child names but the second column (emp_name) is empty!  What am I missing?  I am using Access 2010.

Comment: You are running into *what* problem? I only see a query and a "it does not work" statement. What does your schema look like? What would you like to do? What should happen and what does not happen?

Comment: simple: **customer.child_name** doesn't have an equal value of **emp_name** in any row of the **employee** table.

Answer (score 3):

The LEFT JOIN means that you'll get everything from the first table even if it doesn't have a corresponding row on the second table, if you only what rows from the first table that have a matching row on the second one use INNER JOIN.